# Codeigniter CSRF response format

Tags: json, codeigniter, csrf

I am using a predefined response format for all my ajax calls.

If the request is `success` then the server will respond :

```
{"status":true,"data":{"name":"person","age":2}}
```

Please note `data` is not necessary.

and if the request failed then i will get

```
{"status":false,"reason":"You are not authorised."}
```

SO every response have a `status` field , if status is `FALSE` then there will be `reason` field.

The problem is that now i enables `CSRF` protection in Codeigniter and if the token expired/failed the system outputs

```
The action you have requested is not allowed.
```

this is HTML content.

Is it possible to  extend the security class ,so that if the request is through Ajax then it will keep json_encoded format else use the html format.(i do not want to modify the core)

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it helps http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/182631/P15/#997252

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message is rendered from the `CI_Exceptions::show_error` method (located in system/core). You can [extend this class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html) by the usual way and override this method in order to catch this error and return whatever you want.

You can get rid of the call inside the `CI_Security::csrf_show_error` method by overriding it so it won't simply call

```
show_error('The action you have requested is not allowed.');
```

This is probably more robust.

Alternatively you can attack this inside `CI_Exceptions` class. Since this errors doesn't come with specific error code you will have to match for the message which could break between updates ([currently hardcoded](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Security.php#L280)). The resulting class could look like this:

```
class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions {
    public function show_error($heading, $message, $template = 'error_general', $status_code = 500) {
        if ($message == 'The action you have requested is not allowed.') {
            // handle this error your way
        } else {
            // send every other error to the original handler
            parent::show_error($heading, $message, $template, $status_code);
        }
    }
}
```